# Exception: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

Tags: .net, com-interop, out-of-memory

I am referencing an ActiveX dll in my .NET application and getting an "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program" exception thrown on a user that loads large amounts of data from this ActiveX object.

What is the recommended method to solve this problem?

The company that develops this dll isn't very thrilled to fix the bug, so I'm trying to handle this myself.

Thanks

Comment: "the company that develop this dll isn't very thrilled to fix the bug" - Why?

Comment: because their lazy... and i'm depending on them, so i have to continue use their product

Comment: How much memory does the ActiveX dll try to consume prior to falling over?

Comment: it gets to about 500MB. it's XP operting system

Comment: It isn't a bug in their code and they are not lazy.  It just doesn't make sense to put tens of thousands of records in a user interface control.  Nobody can find anything back, they are probably just happy that they won't have to after it falls over.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is the ActiveX control that is consuming the memory and not your code, I'm not sure that there *is* anything that you can do, other than perhaps attempt to use the ActiveX control in a slightly different way that either uses less memory or protects against this exception for example:

- Prevent someone loading too many data sets at once.
- Somehow split a large data set into several smaller data sets.
- Use a 64bit process.
- Try splitting the memory pressure over multiple processes somehow.

Of course this will all depend on the specifics of the ActiveX control, and so its difficult to say whether or not this is feasible without knowing more about the control.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416416/getting-outofmemoryexception-at-runtime-with-the-message-insufficient-memory-to/3416521#3416521) there is a machine.config setting which allows you to increase the per-process memory limit which may help a little - you should also read the second answer on this question which goes into more detail about why this exception happens.