# C# BinaryFormatter throws OutOfMemoryException while serializing datatable into memory stream

Tags: c#, datatable, out-of-memory

I have 1 million records in my DataTable. I need to send this data to desktop application via bytes. Thus, I am using BinaryFormatter to serialize DataTable. Below is the code I have used.

```
        if (dt != null)// dt is the datatable with the million records
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, dt); // here it throws exception "System.OutOfMemoryException"
            _data = stream.GetBuffer();
        }
```

But it throws **System.OutOfMemoryException**. What I don't get is why the exception is being thrown when I have enough virtual memory available. Also the for .Net 3.5 the size of any object is limited to 2 GB but it does not cross 2 GB.

**P.S** I have 2 GB RAM available and almost 700MB paged pool.

Below is the Stack Trace of the exception thrown

```
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at System.IO.StringWriter.ToString()
   at System.Data.DataSet.GetRemotingDiffGram(DataTable table)
   at System.Data.DataTable.SerializeDataTable(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, Boolean isSingleTable, SerializationFormat remotingFormat)
   at System.Data.DataTable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
```

Comment: Well, what is `dt`? How big is it? Without that: we're firing blind here.

Comment: There are plenty of general answers explaining that exception, e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1291735/1997232). You have to be more specific: how `dt` looks like, what data inside, etc.

Comment: You may want to read this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/

Comment: `DataTable` defaults to the xml serialization format that was used in 1.*; however, this is incredibly inefficient, so you will probably get a lot of benefit by telling it *not to do that*: via `dt.RemotingFormat = System.Data.SerializationFormat.Binary;`

Comment: also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416416/getting-outofmemoryexception-at-runtime-with-the-message-insufficient-memory-to

Comment: @MarcGravell dt is the DataTable with 1 million records.

Comment: @JDoshi well, we can reasonably expect it to be non-trivially large, then, especially if you use the xml layout

Comment: @MarcGravell Switching to 64 bit application is not a fissible option right now since client is heated up :p

Comment: @JDoshi and if I had mentioned 64-bit, that might be relevant...

Comment: @MarcGravell I need to send the bytes and not the datatable. Then how can dt.RemotingFormat = System.Data.SerializationFormat.Binary; be usefull??

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry it was not you to suggest that one!

Comment: @JDoshi because `BinaryFormatter` *is the remoting formatter*; hence why the stack-trace is `GetRemotingDiffGram`. Remoting doesn't always mean remote call; it can also mean data transfer, which is what it is talking about in this case. Seriously: it applies here. Try it.

Comment: @MarcGravell I got your point. But my issue is that I need to return bytes. How shall I achieve that ?? Sorry to irritate but I am newbie :(

Comment: @JDoshi you will still be serializing to a `MemoryStream`, and you will still be able to pass it around as bytes; all this does is change the format that it uses **internally** to store the data, into one that is much more efficient. The data it represents will be identical, and it will rehydrate into the exact same model.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks!! for the help and explaining me the steps :)